# One web font is loaded but not the other, despite identical settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, webfonts

I have a Rails 4 app with two separate web fonts, that both work flawlessly locally.

Once deployed to Heroku, only one of the fonts work. The other one renders an error in the console ("Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)").

application.css (the first one is the fawlty):

```
@font-face    {font-family: scp; src: url("/assets/Source_Code_Pro/SourceCodePro-Medium.ttf"); font-weight: 400;}
@font-face    {font-family: futura; src: url("/assets/Futura/FuturaT.ttf"); font-weight: 400;}
```

config/application.rb

```
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```